# How can i draw a perfect multiples lines spiral with loop & points?

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

I have a code to draw spiral with points

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = 400;
var centerY = 400;
cxt.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

var count = 0;
var increment = 3/32;
var distance = 10;

for (theta = 0; theta < 50; theta++) {
  var newX = centerX + distance * Math.cos((theta) * 4 * Math.PI * increment );
  var newY = centerY + distance * Math.sin(((theta)) * 4 * Math.PI * increment );
  cxt.fillText("o", newX, newY);
  count++;
  if (count % 4 === 0) {
    distance = distance + 10;
  }

}
cxt.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8l6l.png)
[image]

Notice how many time i change the increment value, there're always a line that have more or less points than others

```
increment = 5/32;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo8EC.png)

[image]

Is this possible to draw a perfect spiral with all lines has the same lenght with each other?

Answer (score 2):

There are a quite a few issues here. Like @Anytech said, you need to first decide how many arms (strings of dots) you want. In your screenshot, it looks like you have 5 arms, but you probably got that by accident. I've replaced the "o" with the distance to help visualize the problem:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = 200;
var centerY = 200;
cxt.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

var count = 0;
var increment = 3/32;
var distance = 10;

for (theta = 0; theta < 50; theta++) {
  var newX = centerX + distance * Math.cos((theta) * 4 * Math.PI * increment );
  var newY = centerY + distance * Math.sin(((theta)) * 4 * Math.PI * increment );
  cxt.fillText(distance, newX, newY);
  count++;
  if (count % 4 === 0) {
    distance = distance + 10;
  }

}
cxt.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

As you can see, the first four dots are at distance 10, the 5th one is at distance 20, from there, you've already broken the rhythm.

Assuming you still want 5 arms, increase the distance every 5 dots by checking `count % 5 === 0`, instead of `count % 4 === 0`.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = 200;
var centerY = 200;
cxt.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

var count = 0;
var increment = 3/32;
var distance = 10;

for (theta = 0; theta < 50; theta++) {
  var newX = centerX + distance * Math.cos((theta) * 4 * Math.PI * increment );
  var newY = centerY + distance * Math.sin(((theta)) * 4 * Math.PI * increment );
  cxt.fillText(distance, newX, newY);
  count++;
  if (count % 5 === 0) {
    distance = distance + 10;
  }

}
cxt.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

Also, a full circle is `2 * Math.PI`. If you can use `Math.cos((theta) * 2 * Math.PI * increment)`, increment becomes the arc the dot will travel after each paint. If increment is `1/5`, you will get five straight lines. If increment is a little bit more than `1/5`, you will get the curve effect you want.

And one final detail, we usually call context `ctx`, instead of `cxt`. Combining all of the above, the output looks like this

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = 200;
var centerY = 200;
ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

var count = 0;
var increment = 1.02/5;
var distance = 10;

for (theta = 0; theta < 50; theta++) {
  var newX = centerX + distance * Math.cos((theta) * 2 * Math.PI * increment );
  var newY = centerY + distance * Math.sin(((theta)) * 2 * Math.PI * increment );
  ctx.fillText('o', newX, newY);
  count++;
  if (count % 5 === 0) {
    distance = distance + 10;
  }

}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

**EDIT**

After having a chat with the question raiser, I realize the problem also has to to with `fillText` using the bottom-left corner of the string as the starting point for the paint. To address the issue, we must plot actual circles, instead of letter 'o'.

Here is the final result (concentric circles added to show perfect symmetry)

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = 200;
var centerY = 200;
ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

var count = 0;
var increment = 1.05/5;
var distance = 10;

for (theta = 0; theta < 50; theta++) {
  var newX = centerX + distance * Math.cos((theta) * 2 * Math.PI * increment );
  var newY = centerY + distance * Math.sin(((theta)) * 2 * Math.PI * increment );
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  //ctx.fillText('o', newX, newY); <== this will be off-center
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.arc(newX, newY, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
  ctx.stroke();
  count++;
  if (count % 5 === 0) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, distance, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
    ctx.stroke();
    distance = distance + 10;
  }

}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: i change the increment to 1.05/5, it's still unbalance

Comment: Did you use `count % 5` instead of `count % 4`?

Comment: Take a look, it is balanced: https://jsbin.com/cejobuvanu/edit?html,output

Comment: the left-bottom branch is shorter than other, change number to "o" & you see easier

Comment: sorry I really couldn't see the issue. Is it shorter by missing a dot? I could count exactly 10 dots per arm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202775/discussion-between-chuanqi-sun-and-han-tran).

Comment: Hi, i found an image cosnisdered to be an perfect spiral with all arms has the same length, can we draw some thing like this with code? imgur.com/RPy69Xo

Answer (score 1):

The circumference of a circle is `2 * PI * radius`.

We can use this to determine what angle step to make to cover a distance on the circumference. Thus the angle that sweeps a given distance along the curve is `distance / radius` (Note this is not the straight line distance, but the distance ALONG the CURVE)

Though you are creating a spiral and the distance for an angle step is a little longer (as the line moves outward) the approximation will suffice for the human eye.

So changing your code with the following steps

- Remove `increment`
- Change `distance` to `radius`
- Rather than limit the number of turns, we will use the radius to limit the max radius of the spiral. Adding `maxRadius = 350`  to fit the canvas
- Add `lineLength` to set the approx distance between each point in pixels.
- Change the for loop to a while loop as we are going to step angle inside the loop.
- Rename `theta` to `angle` (we are programmers not mathematicians)
- Rather than use a character to draw each point we will create a path of arcs so that the positioning can be precise. That will add some 2D context setup code.
- Rather than step out every 4 points (as that no longer will work) we will make the radius a function of angle. With that add some constants to control the radius function.
- `radiusMin` defines the min radius (starting radius)
- `radiusScale` defines the rate per turn in pixel that the spiral moves out.
- Remove `count` as its no longer needed
- Inside the loop calculate the radius. As we have difined the radius growth as a rate per turn we divide the `radiusScale / (Math.PI * 2)` so the radius is `radius = angle * (radiusScale / (Math.PI * 2)) + radiusMin;`
- Inside the loop we step the angle to match the distance we want to move `angle += lineLength / radius;` which is derived from the circumference formula (and why we use radians for angles)
- Change `cxt` to the more idiomatic  `ctx`
- Add `moveTo` to move to the start of each circle.
- Add `ctx.arc` to define the circle
- When all circles are defined, after the loop draw the path with `ctx.stroke()`

The code below. As I have only approximated your spiral you can play with the constants to make it fit your needs. Also Note that for the inner spiral, longer line distances will not work as well.

```js
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
const centerX = 400;
const centerY = 400;

const markRadius = 2;   // radius of each circle mark in pixels
const maxRadius = 350;  // 50 pixel boarder
const lineLength = 20;  // distance between points in pixels 
const radiusScale = 80; // how fast the spiral moves outward per turn 
const radiusMin = 10;   // start radius

var angle = 0, radius = 0;

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStye = "black";
ctx.beginPath();

while (radius < maxRadius) {
  radius = angle * (radiusScale / (Math.PI * 2)) + radiusMin;
  angle += lineLength / radius;
  const x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  const y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  ctx.moveTo(x + markRadius, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, markRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

If you want separate spirals then it is a minor modification of the above

- Define the number of arms in the spiral `armCount`
- Define the rate that the arms turn as the move out "spiralRate"
- Just for fun animate the `spiralRate`

```js
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
const centerX = 200;
const centerY = 200;

const markRadius = 2;   // radius of each circle mark in pixels
const maxRadius = 190;  // 50 pixel boarder
const armCount = 8;  // Number of arms
const radiusScale = 8; // how fast the spiral moves outward per turn 
const radiusMin = 10;   // start radius

function drawSpiral(spiralRate) { // spiralRate in pixels per point per turn
  var angle = 0, radius = radiusMin;

  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStye = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();


  while (radius < maxRadius) {
    angle += (Math.PI * 2) / armCount + (spiralRate/ radius);
    radius = angle * (radiusScale / (Math.PI * 2)) + radiusMin;
    const x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    const y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle);
    ctx.moveTo(x + markRadius, y);
    ctx.arc(x, y, markRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  }
  
  ctx.stroke();
}


function mainLoop(time) {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   drawSpiral(Math.sin(time / 4000) * 2); // occilate spiral rate every ~ 24 seconds
   requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, the arms still has the same problem as mine, i found a spiral with perfect arms leght, do you know how to draw them like this? https://imgur.com/RPy69Xo

Answer (score 0):

After changing the code to increment in number form you can see that the "spiral" is not generated in the expected line.

You will ned to work out how many spiral arms you want and calculate that with the stoplimit.

The increment value is also never used.

```
// var increment = 6/45; 
var stoplimit = 51;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Anytech/spzyufev/4/